# Set different keyboard settings for two different users or applications on Mac?

Tags: keyboard, imac, user-account, settings

One user of uses Microsoft Remote Desktop to use Windows-based, industry-specific software which requires constant use of function keys, while other users **never** uses function keys.

I know that we can just press the **fn** key to access `F1` to `F12`, or change the setting globally to require the **fn** key for the special functions (brightness, volume etc) instead, but can this setting be different for different users or, better still, different apps?

We have the British English Magic Keyboard with Numeric Keypad, and an iMac running macOS High Sierra 10.13.6.

Answer (score 1):

The `Use F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys` setting is applicable on a per user basis.

[image]

If the two users in your case have different user accounts, it will be very easy to enable/disable this setting for appropriate users.

It is not natively possible to configure this setting on a per app basis though.

Comment: Many thanks - my mistake, I thought it had changed the setting for all users but you're quite right.

Comment: @user299046 Kindly accept the answer if it worked for you. That will be helpful for other users having similar query.